# How is semantic web relevant to ASP.NET MVC Web Development?

Tags: asp.net, semantic-web

Are there any specific libraries for asp.net that are promising?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## In short,

It isn't. It won't be for a long time.

It's a collection of technologies that, for all intents and purposes, don't exist yet for mainstream development. I know this may not quite get at the spirit of your question, but really, related specifically to ASP.NET MVC, there is nothing you really care about yet.

Web 2.0 stuff like AJAX, web services, and all are really what you're interested in.

Answer (score 2):

There are some interesting semantic web technologies that are built on the .NET stack and may be used in conjunction with ASP.NET MVC.  I am a big fan of [Intellidimension's](http://www.intellidimension.com/) technology as it enables you to use SQL server as a graph store and has a rich .NET SDK for interacting with any type of graph repository including (SQL, Web Service, Third Party, etc...).

@Anthony Kanago is correct in pointing out that there is nothing that relates ASP.NET MVC to Semantic Web technologies or standards specifically but that could also be said about the link between ASP.NET MVC and traditional relational repositories.